# python- is beautifulsoup misreporting my html?

Tags: python, macos, configuration, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have two machines each, to the best of my knowledge, running python 2.5 and BeautifulSoup 3.1.0.1.

I'm trying to scrape http://utahcritseries.com/RawResults.aspx, using:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

base_url = "http://www.utahcritseries.com/RawResults.aspx"

data=urllib2.urlopen(base_url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
i = 0
table=soup.find("table",id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridEvents')
#table=soup.table
print "begin table"
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:10]:
    i=i + 1
    col = row.findAll('td')
    date = col[0].string
    event = col[1].a.string
    confirmed = col[2].string
    print '%s - %s' % (date, event)
print "end table"
print "%s rows processed" % i
```

On my windows machine,I get the correct result, which is a list of dates and event names.  On my mac, I don't.  instead, I get

```
3/2/2002 - Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
None - Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
3/23/2002 - Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
None - Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
4/2/2002 - Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
None - Saltair Time Trial
4/9/2002 - Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
None - DMV Criterium
4/16/2002 - Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
```

What I'm noticing is that when I

```
print row
```

on my windows machine, the tr data looks exactly the same as the source html.  Note the style tag on the second table row.  Here's the first two rows:

```
<tr>
<td>
 3/2/2002
</td>
<td>
 <a href="Event.aspx?id=226">
  Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
 </a>
</td>
<td>
 Confirmed
</td>
<td>
 <a href="Event.aspx?id=226">
  Points
 </a>
</td>
<td>
 <a disabled="disabled">
  Results
 </a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#EFEFEF;">
<td>
 3/16/2002
</td>
<td>
 <a href="Event.aspx?id=227">
  Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
 </a>
</td>
<td>
 Confirmed
</td>
<td>
 <a href="Event.aspx?id=227">
  Points
 </a>
</td>
<td>
 <a disabled="disabled">
  Results
 </a>
</td>
</tr>
```

On my mac when I print the first two rows, the style information is removed from the tr tag and it's moved into each td field.  I don't understand why this is happening.  I'm getting None for every other date value, because BeautifulSoup is putting a font tag around every other date.  Here's the mac's output:

```
<tr>
<td>
 3/2/2002
</td>
<td>
 <a href="Event.aspx?id=226">
  Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
 </a>
</td>
<td>
 Confirmed
</td>
<td>
 <a href="Event.aspx?id=226">
  Points
 </a>
</td>
<td>
 <a disabled="disabled">
  Results
 </a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF">
<td>
 <font color="#333333">
  3/16/2002
 </font>
</td>
<td>
 <font color="#333333">
  <a href="Event.aspx?id=227">
   Rocky Mtn Raceway Criterium
  </a>
 </font>
</td>
<td>
 <font color="#333333">
  Confirmed
 </font>
</td>
<td>
 <font color="#333333">
  <a href="Event.aspx?id=227">
   Points
  </a>
 </font>
</td>
<td>
 <font color="#333333">
  <a disabled="disabled">
   Results
  </a>
 </font>
</td>
</tr>
```

My script is displaying the correct result under windows-what do I need to do in order to get my Mac to work correctly?

Comment: Are you saying the HTML is different depending on your client browser?  Are you saying the site gives different HTML to a windows machine than it does to your mac?  That's not unusual, BTW.

Comment: no, i'm saying the output of print table look different across two different machines.  In the browser, the html looks the same.

I don't really know how to verify the version of beautifulSoup that I'm actually using.  On my mac, there is a BeautifulSoup 3.1 .egg in /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in the urlib2 request, not BeautifulSoup:

It might help if you show us the same section of the raw data as returned by this command on both machines:

```
urllib2.urlopen(base_url)
```

This page looks like it might help:
http://bytes.com/groups/python/635923-building-browser-like-get-request

The simplest solution is probably just to detect which environment the script is running in and change the parsing logic accordingly.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.uname() 
('Darwin', 'skom.local', '9.6.0', 'Darwin Kernel Version 9.6.0: Mon Nov 24 17:37:00 PST 2008; root:xnu-1228.9.59~1/RELEASE_I386', 'i386')
```

Or get microsoft to use web standards :)

Also, didn't you use mechanize to fetch the pages? If so, the problem may be there.

Answer (score 2):

There are [documented problems](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html) with version 3.1 of BeautifulSoup.

You might want to double check that is the version you in fact are using, and if so downgrade.